# Wrapped clickable DivElement : event isn't listened

Tags: javascript, dom-events, wrapper

Please, consider the little following code :

```
function Movable(x, y, width, height, background_color) {
    this.html_element = document.createElement("div");
   
    this.html_element.onclick = this.move;
    this.move = function() {
        alert("Clicked !");
    };
    
    this.display = function() {
        document.body.innerHTML += this.html_element.outerHTML;
    };
}
```

I'm trying to add the HTML attribute "onclick" with `move();` as value. This `move` value is actually a function that alerts "Clicked !" when the final-user clicks on this HTML element.

But it doesn't work. When I inspect the source, it seems that the property `onclick` isn't added to this HTML element.

Do you know why and how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`document.body.innerHTML += this.html_element.outerHTML;` is the problem. That's just about the worst way to go about adding an element to a page.

Your handler has nothing to do with HTML, so it is being lost when you serialize the element to HTML with the `outerHTML` call. Not to mention that you're serializing and destroying *all* the nodes under the `document.body`, and then turning them back into new nodes, which will make them lose handlers and other data too.

Instead just do use `.appendChild()` to add the Element node:

```
document.body.appendChild(this.html_element)
```

Also, you're assigning `this.move` as the handler *before* you create it, which will just assign `undefined` unless there's a `Movable.prototype.move` with a handler.

```
function Movable(x, y, width, height, background_color) {
    this.html_element = document.createElement("div");

    this.move = function() {
        alert("Clicked !");
    };

    this.html_element.onclick = this.move;

    this.display = function() {
        document.body.appendChild(this.html_element);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Do you know why I can't access the `style` property within the function `move` ? =/

Comment: @Lern-X: `this.style` should give you that property, so `this.style.display = "none"` for example will hide the element.

Comment: Oh, you mean *your* display function. That's because the value of `this` will be the element, not your object. This is a common problem, and you'll find many different solutions if you search. One approach I like is to use the `EventListener` interface. But there are other approaches too.

Comment: The `onclick` changes the `move`'s context no ? (edit : so it changes the value of `this` ?)

Comment: @Lern-X: In JS, the value of `this` is determined at the site of the call. It's much like an immutable function parameter, and is lexically defined in every call. JS now has "arrow functions" that do not define a `this` value, so it closes over the `this` from its outer scope, letting you use that value instead..

Comment: Okay thank you. I used the method `bind` to solve this problem.